# Grouping an array of objects by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

I have this array of objects, and I want them to group by their specific key, in this case `tags`

```
var items = [
    {id: 0, tags: ["a"], name: "foo"},
    {id: 1, tags: [], name: "bar"},
    {id: 2, tags: ["a"], name: "bazz"},
    {id: 3, tags: ["b"], name: "wah"},
    {id: 4, tags: ["c"], name: "ikr"},
    {id: 5, tags: ["a"], name: "wtf"},
    {id: 6, tags: ["a","b"], name: "gtg"},
    {id: 7, tags: ["c"], name: "afk"}
]
```

And so I used underscore, like so:

```
var groupItems = _.groupBy(items, function(obj) {
  return obj.tags;
});
```

The problem with that is that:

```
{
"a": [
        {"id": 0,"tags": ["a"],"name": "foo"},
        {"id": 2,"tags": ["a"],"name": "bazz"},
        {"id": 5,"tags": ["a"],"name": "wtf"}
     ],
"":  [
        {"id": 1,"tags": [],"name": "bar"}
     ],
"b": [
         {"id": 3,"tags": ["b"],"name": "wah"}
     ],
"c": [
         {"id": 4,"tags": ["c"],"name": "ikr"},
         {"id": 7,"tags": ["c"],"name": "afk"}
     ],
"a,b": [
         {"id": 6,"tags": ["a","b"],"name": "gtg"}
     ]
```

}

If you would also notice, those who has multiple tags, created a `joined` key from the array `tags` which is quite an undesirable result. How can I, group them by `tags` and duplicate the data when they have multiple `tags`

Comment: What you have is an array of objects, not JSON. JSON is a **data-format**, like XML or CSV.

Comment: Ah right, array of json of objects.

Comment: why your `id:6` in result have `"tags": ["a","b"]` but in source `tags: ["a"]`

Comment: Ah, just a typo, I'll fix it

Comment: so what wrong with __.groupBy_?

Comment: @Grundy I think the multiple tags behavior.

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Lmchrq9d/

Comment: so what expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want duplicate entries under each tag when an item has multiple tags `_.groupBy` will not do what you want as it simply splits a collection up (won't duplicate entries).

Instead, you will need to loop over your items manually, then each item's tags and build up your list for you (you could use `_.each` if you wanted):

```
var items = [
    {id: 0, tags: ["a"], name: "foo"},
    {id: 1, tags: [], name: "bar"},
    {id: 2, tags: ["a"], name: "bazz"},
    {id: 3, tags: ["b"], name: "wah"},
    {id: 4, tags: ["c"], name: "ikr"},
    {id: 5, tags: ["a"], name: "wtf"},
    {id: 6, tags: ["a","b"], name: "gtg"},
    {id: 7, tags: ["c"], name: "afk"}
];

var groupItems = {};
for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; i++) {
  for (var t = 0, tag; tag = item.tags[t]; t++) {
    // If we do not have an array for our tag, add one
    groupItems[tag] = groupItems[tag] || [];
    // Push out item onto the tag's list in our groupItems
    groupItems[tag].push(item);
  }
}
```

Which will give you:

```
{
  "a": [
    {"id": 0,"tags": ["a"],"name": "foo"},
    {"id": 2,"tags": ["a"],"name": "bazz"},
    {"id": 5,"tags": ["a"],"name": "wtf"},
    {"id": 6,"tags": ["a","b"],"name": "gtg"}
  ],
  "b": [
    {"id": 3,"tags": ["b"],"name": "wah"},
    {"id": 6,"tags": ["a","b"],"name": "gtg"}
  ],
  "c": [
    {"id": 4,"tags": ["c"],"name": "ikr"},
    {"id": 7,"tags": ["c"],"name": "afk"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution based on your needs, put importance on the readability and maintenance

http://jsfiddle.net/6x6vvukq/

```
var items = [
    {id: 0, tags: ["a"], name: "foo"},
    {id: 1, tags: [], name: "bar"},
    {id: 2, tags: ["a"], name: "bazz"},
    {id: 3, tags: ["b"], name: "wah"},
    {id: 4, tags: ["c"], name: "ikr"},
    {id: 5, tags: ["a"], name: "wtf"},
    {id: 6, tags: ["a"], name: "gtg"},
    {id: 7, tags: ["c"], name: "afk"}
]

function groupByTags(items){

    var grouped = {};    

    items.forEach(function(item){   
        var tags = item.tags;
        if(!tags.length) tags.push("");

        tags.forEach(function(tag){

            if(tag in grouped == false){
                grouped[tag] = [];
            }
            grouped[tag].push(item);

        });        
    });    

    return grouped;

}

console.log(groupByTags(items));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little function that properly handles empty arrays of tags. You may want to replace `forEach` with `for` loop for better performance and add some type checks to make this function more generic and less error prone.

```
function groupBy(arr, propName) {
    var grouped = {};

    arr.forEach(function (thing) {
        var values = thing[propName];

        if (!values.length) {
            grouped[''] = grouped[''] || [];
            grouped[''].push(thing);

            return;
        }

        values.forEach(function (value) {
            grouped[value] = grouped[value] || [];
            grouped[value].push(thing)
        });
    });

    return grouped;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cscrak32/

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
items.reduce(function(acc, el) {
  (el.tags.length === 0 ? [""] : el.tags).forEach(function(el2) {
    if (!acc[el2]) acc[el2] = [];
    acc[el2].push(el);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
```

```js
var items = [{
  id: 0,
  tags: ["a"],
  name: "foo"
}, {
  id: 1,
  tags: [],
  name: "bar"
}, {
  id: 2,
  tags: ["a"],
  name: "bazz"
}, {
  id: 3,
  tags: ["b"],
  name: "wah"
}, {
  id: 4,
  tags: ["c"],
  name: "ikr"
}, {
  id: 5,
  tags: ["a"],
  name: "wtf"
}, {
  id: 6,
  tags: ["a", "b"],
  name: "gtg"
}, {
  id: 7,
  tags: ["c"],
  name: "afk"
}]

var result = items.reduce(function(acc, el) {
  (el.tags.length === 0 ? [""] : el.tags).forEach(function(el2) {
    if (!acc[el2]) acc[el2] = [];
    acc[el2].push(el);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre id="res"></pre>
```