# Get unique values from array of dictionaries and create a new dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, express, dictionary

I have a JSON file that looks a little like this:

```
[{
    "name": "Il Brigante",
    "rating": "5.0",
    "match": "87",
    "cuisine": "Italian",
    "imageUrl": "/image-0.png"
}, {
    "name": "Giardino Doro Ristorante",
    "rating": "5.0",
    "match": "87",
    "cuisine": "Italian",
    "imageUrl": "/image-1.png"
}, {
    "name": "Cosme",
    "rating": "5.0",
    "match": "87",
    "cuisine": "Mexican",
    "imageUrl": "/image-1.png"
}]
```

I am trying to loop through the array, identify distinct "cuisine"'s and then create a dictionary with the "name"'s as the value and the matches as an array which will be the key.

Here is an example:

```
{ Italian: 
     [{"name": "Il Brigante",
       "rating": "5.0", etc},
      {"name": "Giardino Doro Ristorante", 
       "rating": "5.0", etc}], 
   Mexican: 
     [{"name": "Cosme", 
       "rating": "5.0", etc}]
 }
```

Would anyone know how to do this? Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!!

Cheers,
Theo

Comment: The structure in your desired result does not make sense. You have arrays with keys....

Comment: @aduss you're right. i fixed that typo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901544/grouping-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce` to create your resulting object.

> [**Array.prototype.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
>
> *The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.*

Here is an example:

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Il Brigante",
  "rating": "5.0",
  "match": "87",
  "cuisine": "Italian",
  "imageUrl": "/image-0.png"
}, {
  "name": "Giardino Doro Ristorante",
  "rating": "5.0",
  "match": "87",
  "cuisine": "Italian",
  "imageUrl": "/image-1.png"
}, {
  "name": "Cosme",
  "rating": "5.0",
  "match": "87",
  "cuisine": "Mexican",
  "imageUrl": "/image-1.png"
}]


var res = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
  if(a[b['cuisine']]) {
    a[b['cuisine']].push( {name: b['name'], rating: b['rating']} )
  } else {
    a[b['cuisine']] = [ {name: b['name'], rating: b['rating']} ]
  }
  return a
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: you're a baller man. thanks so much. you're amazing. coolest answer i've seen on stack.

Comment: you have to hardcode all the members of the object, which you can't possibly tell how many members are in the object

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going for this.

```
var byCuisine = {};

myJSON.map(function (obj) {
    byCuisine[obj.cusine] = byCuisine[obj.cusine] || [];
    //can clone it with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( )) if you want then 
     // delete newObj.cuisine to get something like your structure above.
    byCuisine[obj.cusine].push(obj);
})
```

Comment: thanks so much! trying that out now. will get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider using `Array.prototype.forEach

```
const arr = [{
    "name": "Il Brigante",
    "rating": "5.0",
    "match": "87",
    "cuisine": "Italian",
    "imageUrl": "/image-0.png"
}, {
   "name": "Giardino Doro Ristorante",
    "rating": "5.0",
    "match": "87",
    "cuisine": "Italian",
    "imageUrl": "/image-1.png"
}, {
    "name": "Cosme",
    "rating": "5.0",
    "match": "87",
    "cuisine": "Mexican",
    "imageUrl": "/image-1.png"
}];

const finalObj = {};

    arr.forEach( obj => {

       if ( ! finalObj[obj.cuisine] ) {
          let arr = [];
          arr.push(obj);
          Object.assign(finalObj, {
            [obj.cuisine]: arr
          })
       } else {
          finalObj[obj.cuisine].push(obj)
       }
  });

  console.log(finalObj);
```

This code declares a global `const` variable `finalObj` to hold your desired output.

the `arr` array of object is been looped in other to get all of it's elements which are objects, then we determine if `obj.cusisine` exists on the `finalObj` ( which it does not at the first instance a unique `obj.cuisine` is seen ). An array is created to hold the value of the entire `obj` value